# How can I disable scratch preview window?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

While coding Python, I like Vim's omnicompletion function, but I don't want Scratch Window to pop up at top.

How can I disable it?

(I'm using gVim 7.3)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This behavior is defined by the presence of `preview` in the value of the `'completeopt'` option.

The default value is:

```
menu,preview
```

To remove `preview`, simply add this line to your `~/.vimrc` or modify an existing `completeopt` line:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind the preview window too much, but want to easily close it, you can use the `:pclose` command or `CTRL-W z` keyboard combination see `:help :pclose`.

Comment: Thank you, as a new user that enabled preview by accident - this is the correct answer.